# PHP: DOM get child elements from one parent already pulled from dom

Tags: php, dom

I have a DOM that looks like this:

```
<random>
    <li>text text text <star item="1"/> text text</li>
    <li>text <star item="1"/> text text <star item="2"/> text text</li>
    <li> text text text text </li>
</random>
```

I have pulled out 1 'li' element (`$liToProcess`) using the following code:

```
$liElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
$liCount = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li')->length;
// Select a random li
$useThisItem = rand(0, $liCount-1);
$liToProcess = $liElements->item($useThisItem)->nodeValue;
```

How do I get all the `star` elements (and be able to iterate through them to use the `item="#"`) from the one 'li' element that has already been selected from the DOM?

Comment: * all the star elements* - inner for selected `li` or in `random` ?

Comment: From a single 'li' (which has already been selected at random)

Comment: the same method - `$liToProcess->getElementsByTagName('star');`

Comment: When I do that, that line gets the error "`Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on string`"

Comment: sorry. `$selectedLI->$liElements->item($useThisItem);` and then `$selectedLI->getElementsByTagName('star');`

Comment: i  missed that you take node value

Comment: Yep. Thats right. I just realized that too.